# What does it mean that "A $G$-torsor is like the group $G$ that forgot its identity element"?

Tags: group-theory

A right $G$-torsor (or a [principal homogeneous space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_homogeneous_space)) is defined to be a set $X$ together with a free and transitive right $G$-action $\lhd: X\times G \to X$. It is often said that "A $G$-torsor is like the group $G$ that forgot its identity element". What, roughly does this last statement mean? I've had a hard time understanding it because there is no multiplication operation on $X$.

Comment: Do you know how an affine space is like a vector space that forgot about the origin? It's the same thing...

Comment: @IvoTerek unfortunately I've never quite understood affine spaces either! But now (see my answer below) I think I understand $G$-torsors, so therefore, I feel like I understand affine spaces (which are just a special case of $G$-torsor) as well.

Comment: Skimming over it, I think you got the gist of it, yes. See also the first two pages of  https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/associated_connection.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The group $G$ has a natural structure of $G$-torsor where the application $G\times G\to G$ is simply the multiplication map.

What makes this $G$-torsor special is that it has a distinguished point, namely the neutral element $e\in G$.

Now if you take any $G$-torsor $X$, there is an isomorphism of $G$-torsors $X\simeq G$, but it requires the choice of a distinguished element $x_0\in X$. Indeed, once you choose such an element, you get the isomorphism $G\to X$ defined by
$$g\mapsto g\cdot x_0.$$

So in fact you can say that the map $X\times G\to X$ is the same thing as the multiplication $G\times G\to G$, except that you forgot which element was the neutral element. And once you choose a point in $X$, the correspondence becomes explicit.

It is very analog to the fact that an affine space is a vector space which forgot its origin.

Comment: Is the isomorphism $G\to X$ a set isomorphism or a group isomorphism? If it's a group isomorphism then don't we need to define/inherit a group multiplication on $X$ as well?

Comment: It can't be a group isomorphism because $X$ is not a group. It is a $G$-torsor isomorphism, as stated in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is heavily motivated by [Torsors Made Easy by Joan Baez](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html).

A right $G$-torsor is a set $X$ together with a free and transitive right $G$-action $\lhd: X\times G \to X$. Here free means for each $x\in X$ that $x\lhd g = x$ means $g=e$, the identity element in $G$. Transitive means that for each $x, y \in X$ that there is a $g\in G$ such that $x\lhd g = y$. Together these two properties mean that for each $x,y\in X$ there is a **unique** $g\in G$ denoted by $g_{xy}$ such that $x \lhd g_{xy} = y$.

A group has a multiplication operation $\cdot_G: G\times G \to G$. However, we can also define a division operation by
\begin{align}
/_G: G\times G \to G\\
g/_G h \mapsto g\cdot_G h^{-1}.
\end{align}
Because the $G$-action on $X$ in a $G$-torsor is transitive and free we can define a similar division operation $/_X: X\times X \to G$ on $X$:
$$
/:_X X\times X \to G\\
y/_X x \mapsto g_{xy}.
$$
We can see that $x \lhd y/_X x = x \lhd g_{xy} = y$. We can say that group elements measure the quotient or difference between elements in $X$. This is a sense in which a $G$-torsor is **like** the set $G$.

Now, suppose we select and designate a particular element in $X$ called $x_e \in X$. We can use this element together with the inherited division operation to define an inherited (but non-canonical because of the arbitrariness of $x_e$ in $X$) multiplication operation.

$$
\cdot_X: X\times X \to X\\
x\cdot_X y \mapsto x_e \lhd (x/_X x_e)\cdot_G (y/_X x_e)
$$
Or dropping subscripts and denoting $\cdot_X, \cdot_G, \lhd$ by juxtaposition:
$$
xy = x_e (x/x_e)(y/x_e).
$$
Then the map
$$
\phi:G\to X\\
g\mapsto x_e\lhd g
$$
is a group isomorphism between $G$ and $X$ with the non-canonical multiplication operation $\cdot_X$.

---

### Discussion

> A $G$-torsor is like the group $G$ that forgot its identity element

The first obvious similarity between $G$-torsor $X$ and $G$ is that, just like we can multiply an element of $G$ by an element of $G$ and get an element of $G$ we can multiply an element of $X$ by an element of $G$ and get an element of $X$. However, I find this a bit abstract to draw conclusions/intuition from.

The main useful similarity I see between a $G$-torsor $X$ and the group $G$ is that just like we can divide two elements of $G$ and get an element of $G$, we also divide two elements of $X$ and get an element of $G$. This is the sense in which $G$-torsor $X$ is like $G$. Couched in the language of addition/subtraction instead of multiplication/division, we draw the main conclusions from the Baez article. Essentially a $G$-torsor is a space where the absolute value of values in that space is insignificant (like the space of positions), but where we can take differences between elements of that space and get meaningful values in the group $G$ (like $\mathbb{R}^3$). This will be of relevance to gauge theories.

However, the $G$-torsor $X$ is different than $G$ in that there is no multiplication operation between elements of $X$ that returns another element of $X$.Yet again, however, by making a single arbitrary choice of a distinguished element $x_e\in X$ then we can define an inherited group multiplication on $X$ such that $X \simeq G$ under isomorphism $\phi$ and such that $\phi(e) = x_e$.

I'll add my own commentary that instead of saying "A $G$-torsor is like a group $G$ that forgot its identity element" I would prefer to say "A $G$-torsor is a space where you can divide/subtract elements and get elements from the group $G$." If I want to say more I could say "By arbitrarily distinguishing an element of the $G$-torsor then it is straightforward to establish a (non-canonical) isomorphism between the $G$-torsor and $G$ itself".